# Prove that $x^2 + y^2 = 3(z^2 + m^2)$ has no solutions in integer

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, sums-of-squares

Prove that:
$$
 x^2 + y^2 = 3(z^2 + m^2) 
$$
has no solutions in integer
Except $0 0 0 0$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As 3 divides the right hand side, one must have $$x^2+y^2=0 \mod 3.$$ But $$0^2=0\mod 3,$$ $$1^2=1\mod 3,$$ $$2^2=1\mod 3,$$
 so the only way to have $x^2+y^2=0\mod 3$ is if $x=y=0\mod 3$. We can then write $x=3x_1$ and $y=3y_1$, so
$$3(x^2_1+y^2_1)=z^2+m^2.$$
But this is just the original problem with new variables, so we get $z=3z_1$ and $m=3m_1$. Unless $x=y=z=m=0$, this process will continue indefinitely, which is impossible, as 3 can't divide any positive integer infinitely many times.

Conclusion: $x=y=z=m=0$ is the only integer solution.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of modulo $3$, one can work modulo $8$:
$$a^2\equiv 0,1,4\pmod{8}.$$
That means 
$$a^2+b^2\equiv 0,1,2,4,5\pmod{8}.\tag{1}$$
From (1)
$$3(z^2+m^2)\equiv 0,3,6,4,7\pmod{8}.\tag{2}$$
Compare (2) and (1) we see that
$$x^2+y^2=3(z^2+m^2)\equiv 0,4\pmod{8}$$
which only happens when all $x,y,z,m$ are even. We then can continue by reduction.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** assume that $(x,y,z,m)$ is a minimal solution.  Then prove that $$
3|(x^2 + y^2)\implies 3|x\ \ \ \& \ \ \ 3|y
$$

Comment: Yes, that leads me to that there is another smaller answer, so in case we already had the smallest, it is imposible. We have no solutions Q.E.D

Comment: Nice, but i am very interested if there is other different ways to prove that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to prove it:
It is well known that a positive Integer N is representable as the sum of two squares iff N is of the form:

$N = 2^a · p_1^{2e_1} · ... · p_n^{2e_n} · q_1^{e_1} · ... · q_n^{e_n} $

where the $p_i$ are primes of the form $4k+3$ and $q_i$ primes of the form $4k+1$

It immediatly follows that the left hand side and the right hand side of $x^2 + y^2 = 3(z^2 + m^2)$ don't have the same amout of 3's in it's prime factorization, unless of course both sides are zero.